# How to show/hide contents of table cells for google charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-visualization

I am using a `Google charts table` to display exceptions throw from a server. Now the problem is the errors/exceptions are too long (have too many lines), shown in a cell.

I am wondering how to make each cell only show an excerpt of the error messages, and also added a plus/expansion (`+`) sign at the beginning of the excerpt in the cell. So that when clicking `+`, a modal box pops up, showing all the error messages.

Now I have made the modal box working that when I clicked a cell, a modal box with errors popping up. The questions really comes down to

1. how to write some js functions which abstract the errors to just one or a few line(s) to be shown in a cell;
2. how to add a `+` to the beginning of the cell, and create an event handler for listening events like when clicking the `+`, so that a modal box will pop up immediately;
3. as a side question is there a nice looking gadget for `+` in `Google charts` for table cells.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a code example or jsfiddle. No way to know what you're working with for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. how to write some js functions which abstract the errors to just one
>      or a few line(s) to be shown in a cell

You can **truncate** value in cell with javascript `substring` function

> 2. how to add a + to the beginning of the cell, and create an event
>      handler for listening events like when clicking the +, so that a modal 
>      box will pop up immediately;

You can **enable html** in order to add every thing you want, like a link with '+' symbol, adding option `allowHtml: true` to the `google table`.

See following example, I show the "long message" with an `alert`, you could easily show it with a [jQuery dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or another cool dialog as you like.

```js
const MAX_LENGTH = 30;

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Server IP');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Exception');
  data.addColumn('boolean', 'Critical');
  var logData = [];
  logData.push(formatRow(1, '10.0.0.1', longExp, false));
  logData.push(formatRow(2, '10.0.0.2', longExp, true));
  logData.push(formatRow(3, '10.0.0.2', longExp, false));
  logData.push(formatRow(4, '10.0.0.3', 'Short exception', true));
  logData.push(formatRow(5, '10.0.0.3', longExp, false));
  data.addRows(logData);

var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%', allowHtml: true});
}

var longExp = 'java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/Work/jre1.6.0_45/bin/java": error=13, Permission denied\n at\n java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)\n at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)\n at\njava.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:528)\n at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.exec(DebugPlugin.java:879)\n at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.AbstractVMRunner.exec(AbstractVMRunner.java:91)\n at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.StandardVMRunner.run(StandardVMRunner.java:413)\n org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.environments.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:41)';

function formatRow(id, ip, err_msg, criticity){
  if(err_msg.length > MAX_LENGTH){
    err_msg = err_msg.substring(0, MAX_LENGTH) + "&hellip;";
    err_msg += '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:show(' + id + ')">[more]</a>';
  }
  return [ip, err_msg, criticity]; 
}

function show(id){
  //TODO: get complete message from id
  alert(longExp);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: The code works perfectly, but the only thing is the table cannot display either `&hellip` or `...`. I am using this code to truncate strings: `function truncate(n, useWordBoundary) {
    if (this.length <= n) {
        return this;
    }
    var subString = this.substr(0, n - 1);

    // var err_msg = '<a href="#" onclick="javascript:show(' + id + ')">[more]</a>';
    return (useWordBoundary
        ? subString.substr(0, subString.lastIndexOf(' '))
        : subString) + '...';
}`

Comment: I can't see the problem in that function, please provide a snippets, anyway are you using `&hellip` or `&hellip;`, may be you forget the semicolon?

Comment: it seems `this` mess things up in the `truncate` function, so adding another parameter for the string needed to be truncated, solved the problem, but have to use `...` instead of `&hellip`, although `allowHtml` is enabled.

Comment: I can't understand why... I updated my snippet above and `&hellip;` still works.